# Compiling Android system on Linux Mint

Tags: android, android-source

i have been trying to compile an android Marshmello system with no success.
every time i try to compile i get this error :

```
javac: invalid source release: 1.7s
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
make: *** [out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/ext_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar] Error 41
#### make failed to build some targets (03:04 (mm:ss)) ####
```

when i check my java and javac version i get this:

```
javac 1.7.0_161
java version "1.7.0_161"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.12) (7u161-2.6.12-1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.161-b01, mixed mode)
```

which seems to be the correct version for my system

i have set JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_JAVA_HOME to the following paths in the 
bash.rc file

```
echo $ANDROID_JAVA_HOME   
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64

echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

yet nothing seems to work and i keep getting the same error. can anyone help me? tha

Comment: "1.7s" looks odd to me - should it be "1.7" ?

Comment: exactly, it seems very odd. however this is the error everytime. when i try to compile on nougat i get the same error with 1.8 , which makes sense because i am using java jdk 7.

Answer (score -1):

Configure your project for Instant Run 
Android Studio enables Instant Run by default for projects built using Android plugin for Gradle 2.3.0 and higher.

To update an existing project with the latest version of the plugin:

Open the Settings or Preferences dialog.
Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run and click Update Project, as shown in figure 4.

If the option to update the project does not appear, it’s already up-to-date with the latest Android plugin for Gradle. But make sure the box next to Enable Instant Run is checked.

Figure 4. Updating the Android plugin for Gradle for an existing project

To start using Instant Run, you also need to change the build variant to a debug version of your app and deploy it to a target device running Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher. To learn about more techniques that speed up your build, read Optimize Your Build Speed

Exclude your project from Windows Defender 
On Windows systems, Windows Defender may cause slowdowns while using Instant Run. If you are using Windows Defender, you should exclude your Android Studio project folder from Windows Defender malware scans.

Improve build times when using Crashlytics 
If your version of the Fabric Gradle plugin is lower than 1.21.6, Crashlytics may cause slower build times. To improve build performance while developing your app, you can either update the plugin to the latest version or disable Crashlytics for your debug build variant.

Limitations of Instant Run 
Instant Run is designed to speed up the build and deploy process in most situations. However, there are some aspects to using Instant Run that might affect its behavior and compatibility with your app. If you experience any other issues while using Instant Run, please enable extra logging and report a bug.

Apps don't launch on some physical devices 
Some device manufacturers block apps from automatically launching after being installed on the device. When deploying your app to a physical device using Android Studio 2.3, this restriction breaks the intended behavior of Instant Run and causes the following error output: Error: Not found; no service started. To fix this issue, update Android Studio to 2.3.1 or higher.

Debug mode always uses cold swaps 
On Android Studio 2.3, if you deploy your app by clicking Debug , pushing subsequent code changes by clicking Apply Changes  always results in a cold swap. To learn more, go to issue #234401.

Deploying to multiple devices 
Instant Run uses different techniques to perform hot, warm, and cold swaps that are specific to the API level of the target device. For this reason, while deploying an app to multiple devices at once, Android Studio temporarily turns off Instant Run.

Multidexing your app 
If minSdkVersion is set to 21 or higher, Instant Run automatically configures your app for multidex. Because Instant Run only works with the debug version of your app, you may need to configure your app for multidex when deploying your release build variant.

Running instrumented tests and performance profilers 
Instrumented tests load both the debug APK and a test APK into the same process on a test device, allowing control methods to override the normal lifecycle of the app and perform tests. While running or debugging instrumented tests, Android Studio does not inject the additional methods required for Instant Run and turns the feature off.

While profiling an app, you should disable Instant Run. There is a small performance impact when using Instant Run and a slightly larger impact when overriding methods with a hot swap. This performance impact could interfere with information provided by performance profiling tools. Additionally, the stub methods generated with each hot swap can complicate stack traces.

Using third-party plugins 
Android Studio temporarily disables the Java Code Coverage Library (JaCoCo) and ProGuard while using Instant Run. Because Instant Run only works with debug builds, this does not affect your release build.

Certain third-party plugins that perform bytecode enhancement may cause issues with how Instant Run instruments your app. If you experience these issues, but want to continue using Instant Run, you should disable those plugins for your debug build variant. You can also help improve compatibility with third-party plugins by filing a bug.

Pushing changes to multi-process apps 
Instant Run only instruments your app's main process in order to perform hot swaps and warm swaps. When pushing code changes to other app processes, such as changes to a method implementation or an existing resource, Instant Run performs a cold swap.

Launching your app in a work profile 
If you run your app with Instant Run and open your app using a work profile (or other secondary profile), your app will crash because the instrumented DEX files used by Instant Run are accessible only from the primary profile's user space.

If you want to continue using Instant Run, just avoid opening your app with the work profile and be sure your run configuration does not use the --user user_id flag.

If you need to use your app with the work profile, we recommend you create a new run configuration that includes the --user user_id flag, specifying the work profile user ID. You can find the user ID by executing adb shell pm list users from command line. When you use the --user flag, Android Studio disables Instant Run for only that deployment; Instant Run will work again when you switch to a configuration without the --user flag.

Disable Instant Run 
To disable Instant Run:

Open the Settings or Preferences dialog.
Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run.
Uncheck the box next to Enable Instant Run.

Comment: thank you for your answer, however i am trying to compile the whole system using envsetup followed by lunch. therefore i am not using android studio for the compilation.

Comment: Downvoted because this is a copypaste from https://developer.android.com/studio/run#set-up-ir and has nothing to do with the question